# Shopify Liquid tag nested in liquid tag - any workaround?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm new to Shopify and Liquid. I know that you can't nest a liquid tag within another liquid tag ie:

```
{% something {{ something_else }} %}
```

I was wondering if there is a workaround for this kind of scenario? Possibly involving 'capture' or clever use of 'raw'?

I'm building a site that uses product tags to denote which chocolates go in which products (collection of chocolates). On the product page I can easily return the tags as a list:

```
<ul class="chocolates-menu">
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
    <li><a href="/collections/all/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, I'd like to render *snippets* with file names to match the names of the tags (these will contain an image, chocolate name and chocolate description) ie:

```
<li><a href="/collections/all/{{ tag | handleize }}">{% render '{{ tag }}' %}</a></li>
```

The closest I've got is:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% capture chocolate_tag %}
    {% raw %}{% render{% endraw %} {% raw %}'{% endraw %}{{ tag }}{% raw %}' %}{% endraw %}
  {% endcapture %}
  <li><a href="/collections/all/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ chocolate_tag }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This will output the correct code but as text on the page (rather than parsing it). ie: {% render 'Tag Name Here' %} simply as the text of the list item. Any help from brighter folk, is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are the snippets very different from tag to tag? You could create a snippet with a parameter like `{% render 'tag' with tag as tag %}` or `{% include 'tag', tag: tag %}` thus you will have the tag variable and you can use it inside the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I may be missing something here but this might just be pushing the same issue down to the snippet?  ie my snippet would contain something like: `<img src="{{ 'image_with_tag_name_here.png' | file_img_url: '100x' }}" class="responsive">
<h6 class="chocolate-title">{{ tag }}</h6>
<p class="chocolate-description">Short description, specific to each chocolate shown here</p>`.  Wouldn't the `img` would need a nested liquid tag again? ie: `<img src="{{ '{{ tag }}.png' | file_img_url: '100x' }}" class="responsive">`. I can handle the descriptions with if statements.

Comment: You can do `{% assign filename = tag | concat: ".png" %} ` `src="{{ filename | file_img_url}}"`

Comment: @FabioFilippi this is great. Thank you. For some reason, `concat` wouldn't work. I ended up using `append` instead:  `{% assign chocolate_image_url = tag | replace: ' ', '-' | append: ".png" %}` (the image file names are equivalent to the tag text but with dashes rather than spaces). Really appreciate your help. Hope this proves a useful case study for others.

Comment: Yeah `concat` is for list and `append` is for strings, but I always confuse them!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a snippet for all your chocolates and using the tag as a variable to output what is needed.

Here is a visual representation of what I mean and is kinda clearer from your discussion with @Fabio Filippi

`snippets/chocolate.liquid`

```
{% assign tag_image = tag | append: '.png' %}

{% case tag %}
  {% when 'diet' %}
    <img src="{{ tag_image | file_img_url: '100x' }}" class="responsive" />

  {% when 'dark' %}
    <div>My dark chocolate HTML</div>

  {% when 'white' %}
    <div>My white chocolate HTML</div>

{% endcase %}
```

and how to use:

```
{% render 'chocolate', tag: tag %}
```